# Idea to fill the tile gap after removing the wall

Tags: flooring, tile

I removed the wall in my basement which has a tile floor. I want to fill this gap where the wall was and looking for ways on what i can do which is going to look good. Shared picture is part of the wall and other half of the wall (with door in middle) where the tile lines dont match up. So putting existing tiles is not a good option has the size would vary.

[image]

**UPDATE:**

Other side of the wall

[image]

Complete picture:

[image]

**SOLUTION:**

This is I how ended up solving this problem.

[image]

Comment: Wow.  I'm not even sure how that happened!  The grout line that goes through the door is straight.  How did they get so out of line?

Comment: yeah i was puzzled too.... not sure who ever did it what they were thinking... i bought the house last year.... dont get me started on the ceiling, they did not get the lines straight for the drop ceiling...

Comment: Looks like it's time to bring back the "Some Genius" tag.

Comment: This is a great example of - taking walls out are pretty easy - even load bearing... making it look right after.... not so much.

Comment: Finally i ended up solving the problem. Picture above in the post. thanks guys

Comment: Thanks for the update!  Good solution.

Answer (score 6):

I think I have another solution, but it's not great.

1. Remove the entire row of tiles that affects most of the right hand void.
2. Retile the area on the left, continuing the pattern from above.  You will need to seriously think this through, and maybe intentionally mis-align the tiles a little bit so that the black line on the photo is eyeball straight (Although the void from the removed row will probably be different widths at either end.
3. Retile the removed row with a small, somewhat random shaped mosaic, making a transition strip between the two rooms.

Like I said before, this depends on finding matching tiles, and also finding an acceptable mosaic.

Get a chalk line, and draw it out on the existing tile before you do anything!

[image]

Comment: "crazy tile" is a legit style and one way to deal with oddball tile spacing. Short of retile extensively, "make it a feature" is the only practical approach, in my opinion. Grab-bag some small tiles and go to town.

Answer (score 2):

You really only have one choice.  Pop up the cut tiles and replace them with new ones. This assumes that you can find tiles that match.

1. Cut the grout lines around all tiles.
2. While wearing safety glasses, pry up the cut tiles.
3. Clean the subfloor of old mortar as best you can.
4. Apply new tiles (Yes, I'm hand waving! - how to do this is readily searchable).
5. After about 24 hours, fill the gaps with grout.

Depending on how you are going to finish the exposed wood, you may be able to avoid replacing the tile on the bottom right if you cover it.

EDIT (After further photos).
I stand by my answer on the right side, but and totally stymied by the left.  And the angles just make it worse.

At this stage, I'd look at replacing the entire floor as the **correct** solution, which is a lot of work.  You may wish to hire an experienced professional.

Other options:

- Fill the gaps with mortar or any old tile of appropriate thickness., and carpet the whole area.
- With a tile blade on a circular saw and a good straight edge, cut out the the affected area, and redo with another tile, creating a transition zone of contrasting colour and angles.  However, the cut edge will be a bit sharp.  You may want to install transition strips.
- Rebuild the wall.

Comment: This is the answer.   There are only 4 tiles.   If you can't find the exact match - I would go with something way different to accent it.

Comment: As i mentioned in the question, the spacing is bigger than the actual size of the tile. It will leave a 2 inch gap on one side if i try to place the tile as a whole. This is the picture of one side of the wall, other side of the wall has bigger gaps.

Comment: Can you post a full picture?

Comment: I have updated the question above with more info. thanks

Answer (score 2):

**Make it a feature!**

My quickest, cheapest fix for this would be to get some small, maybe almost mosaic tiles, in a heavily contrasting color, blue, slate, or something. I'd maybe cut away a bit more of the tiles around it, and fill it in with the contrasting tile. You'd end up with a marker of the old floorplan. If it ends up looking terrible, you're only out a tiny number of tiles.

The lack of lining up tiles would be less obvious with this clear marker.

Answer (score 1):

If you have any extra tiles of the same type or if they still sell that pattern than I would recommend replacing all cut tiles. Looks like you will need to replace 5 tiles.

Edit:
Based on the new photos, I would agree with Chris' answer. A full replacement would be the best option. Another possibility would be to cut the floor at some point and redo a subsection of the flooring.

Comment: Doesn't look like the other section matches up to replace tiles.

Comment: @JACK, yeah the additional photos weren't present at the time of posting.

Answer (score 1):

Just a crazy, low budget idea. For the short-term.

Clean thoroughly.
Fill the caps with tile cement. Same level as the tiles.
Mimic the grout lines.

Once dry, ask a local artist to 'paint' the tiles. There are paint techniques that can copy this.

You can even cover the painted surfaces with a clear, glossy finish to match the rest of the floor's surface.

Comment: "fill the caps..." is that a typo for "Fill the _gaps_"? By "tile cement", do you mean the mastic that holds the tiles down? I'm not sure that's going to fill, setup, or have much in the way of durability - it's not designed to be a finished surface, it's designed to be glue. Also, faux finish painting is rarely a "low budged" option unless you can do it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Well I see what happened, the gaps between the tiles are irregular sized.

The mess where the short wall came out looks easily recoverable
you probably only need to replace the six cut tiles.

The long wall is a different matter. you'll need to pull more tiles around that to be able to merge the two patterns.

you'll probably wan to start with tile-sized cards placed on the floor (or stuck with temporary glue like blu-tack) to figure out which tiles to pull.